# Threads and Customviews

Tags: android, debugging

I have a **Customview** which contains a function which is used to read contents of a unipenfile and return a gesture.In the main Activity I wish to select my directory manually then I get a list of all files in that directory.Now I wish to call a **ProgressDialog** and in a new Thread for each files get the gesture and save it to my gesturelibrary.. .It is showing the **progressdialog** but its not saving the gestures in my gesture library?**Can anyone tell me if there is an better way to do it?**

here is the Addgesture Function

```
public void addgestures()
        {
            count=0;
            files=null;
            if(dir.isDirectory())   
            {
                files=dir.listFiles();
            }
             pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "adding files", true,false);
             Thread thread = new Thread();
             thread.start();
        }
             public void run() {

                 for( File aFile : files ) 
                {
                    gest=cView.batchprocess(aFile.getPath());
                    if(gest==null)
                        Log.v("paths", aFile.getPath());
                    String name=dirname+"_"+count;
                    saveGesture(name, gest);
                    System.out.println(name+" "+"Success");
                    count++;
                     handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
         }
             private Handler handler = new Handler() {
                 @Override
                 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                         pd.dismiss();   
                 }
         };
```

**here cView is just an object of Customview class** i.e

```
cView = (customview)findViewById(R.id.customview1);
```

and here is the code of my **batchprocess** method in customview

```
public Gesture batchprocess(String file)
    {
        Filename=file;
        flagScale=1; // Initially flagScale=1 to read the points from the file
        dealloc(); //make the structures blank 
        makeShape(); //call the function

        scale();   //call the scaling function
        dealloc(); //make the structures blank again
        flagScale=2;  //will take the points from the arraylist

        makeShape();
        return my_final;
}
```

**makeshape,dealloc and scale** are regular methods in the customview class

and my_final is a gesture which is being obtained by the above 3 function,as of now the method batchprocess is correctly done as I have previously tested it with individual files

Comment: No-one is going to go through ~1000 lines of code and fix the problem for you. Edit your question to include the *relevant* code; not the whole file.

Comment: I just made the changes.Please help now!